# Sharepoint to ASP.net MVC file download

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

I am quite ashamed to ask this question but somehow I am missing something.

**Scenario**

There is a sharepoint instance
There is a document list in sharepoint with three files
I have a asp.net MVC Portal which connects with Sharepoint instance
In a view it shows the list of files (3 in my case)
When user clicks on the item, the file is to be downloaded.

## Problem

The file is downloaded but when you try to open it, word says the file downloaded is corrupt.

I have googled it and tried every variation of code. Only variation that works is to save the file on server and then download it to the client which as you know is not feasible

this is my code

As mentioned above the Sharepoint login,authentication etc all works correctly
fileref is the sharepoint path of the file
len is retrieved from Sharepoint 
//int len= int.Parse(oListItemDoc.FieldValues["File_x0020_Size"].ToString());

```
string filePath = fileRef;
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(GetSharePointUrl());
        clientContext = SharepointAuthorisation(clientContext);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
        {
            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = Path.GetFileName(fileRef),

                // always prompt the user for downloading, set to true if you want 
                // the browser to try to show the file inline
                Inline = true,
            };
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            byte[] fileArr=DownloadFile(title, clientContext, filePath,len,extension, "");
            //FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef.ToString());
            //byte[] arr = new byte[len];
            //fileInfo.Stream.Read(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);
            //return arr;

            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            //return new FileStreamResult(fileInfo.Stream,  "application /octet-stream");// vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
            return  File(fileArr, "application/docx" , Path.GetFileName(fileRef));

        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }



public byte[] DownloadFile(string title, ClientContext clientContext, string fileRef, int len, string itemExtension, string folderName)// Renamed Function Name getdownload to DownloadFiles 
    {
        if (itemExtension == ".pdf")
        {
            //string completePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), folderName);
            //string PdfFile = completePath + "/" + "PDF";
            ////if (!Directory.Exists(PdfFile))
            //{
            //    Directory.CreateDirectory(PdfFile);
            //}

            FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef.ToString());
            byte[] arr = new byte[len];
            fileInfo.Stream.Read(arr, 0, arr.Length);
            return arr;
        }
        else
        {

            FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef.ToString());
            byte[] arr = new byte[len];
            fileInfo.Stream.Read(arr, 0, arr.Length);
            return arr;

        }




    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: is there any simple sample project for this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably it occurs since file size is determined incorrectly. Try to *remove* any dependency to file size from `DownloadFile` method as demonstrated below:

```
public static byte[] DownloadFile(ClientContext ctx,string fileUrl)
{
   var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, fileUrl);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Vadim thanks for taking the time to help me. 
It worked like a charm mate.
Thank you so much for taking the time and pains to write a code snippet.

Comment: @Vadim Gremyachev could you plz have a look at this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722472/download-a-file-from-sharepoint-using-c-sharp-to-default-download-location-in-br)