# Download a file from sharepoint using c# to default download location in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, download

I am trying to download a file from sharepoint site using C#.I am able to download file from sharepoint site but we need to specify the destination location. how can we download the file to default download location of the browser without specifying the destination path.

```
 var downloadPath = @"D:\out\";
            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://testsharepoint.sharepoint.com");
            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "Password12".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
            ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("spuser@ABC.com", passWord);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, "/sites/Test/Test.docx");
            var fileName = Path.Combine(downloadPath, Path.GetFileName("/sites/Test/Test.docx"));
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
            {
                fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution to this problem. Instead of copying filestream to a path,I return the filestream from the controller.Below is my code.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult Download()
    {          
        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://ABC.sharepoint.com");
        SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in "Pass@word12".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
        ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("abc@gmail12.com", passWord);
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, "/sites/Test/testdoc.docx");        
        return File(fileInfo.Stream, "application/octet-stream", "testdoc.docx");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since OpenBinaryDirect is not available for .NET core app,, you can use OpenBinaryStream in your service class and return the file as a stream to the browser. Something like this.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = web.GetFileByUrl(url);
ctx.Load(file, f => f.Name);
ctx.ExecuteQuery(); 
   
ClientResult<Stream> data = await Task.Run(() => file.OpenBinaryStream()); 
ctx.Load(file); 
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

var response = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response; 
response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + file.Name + "\""); 
response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; 
await data.Value.CopyToAsync(response.Body); 
data.Value.Dispose();
await response.Body.FlushAsync();
```

Remember, if success, `return new EmptyResult();` from controller.